# Show that the orthogonal group acts transitively on the sphere $S^n.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, orthogonal-matrices, k-theory, fibration

Show that the orthogonal group $$ O(n + 1) = \{ A \in GL(n+1 , \mathbb{R}) \mid A^{-1} = A^{T}\}$$acts transitively on the sphere $S^n,$ with stabilizer subgroup $O(n).$ Then use this to determine, with justification, the relationship between $i$ and $n$ so that $$\pi_i(O(n)) \cong \pi_i(O(n + 1)) \cong \pi_i(O(n + 2)) \cong \cdots . $$

**I got the following hint:**

You need the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem from algebra, and the fact that if $G$ is a Lie group, then $G_{x} \rightarrow G \rightarrow Gx $ is a fibre sequence.

Still, I am unable to fill the details, could anyone help me in doing so, please?

Comment: Thinking about each $O(n)$ as the subgroup of rotations and reflections in $GL(n)$, this is intuitively obvious, wouldn't you say? Of course, intuitively obvious does not mean proven, but still.

Comment: Note that $A^T = A^{-1}$ iff the columns of $A$ are orthonormal. For $v\in S^n$ pick an orthonormal basis $b_1,\dots, b_n$ for the orthogonal complement of $v$, and let $A\in O(n+1)$ be the matrix whose columns are $v, b_1,\dots,b_n$. Then $A(e_1) = v$ where $e_1$ is the column vector $(1,0,\dots,0)^T$. (Note that $A$ is not unique with this property, there are $O(n)$ many matrices sending $e_1$ to $v$.)

Comment: What else have you tried so far? Have you identified the stabilizer of a point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that we already know that the action is transitive. Then what is the stabilizer of the point $v=(0,...,0,1) \in S^n?$ I claim that if we let $O(n)$ be identified with the subgroup of $O(n+1)$ of all matrices of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & \vdots \\
  & 0\\
\dots 0  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A \in O(n)$, then $O(n)$ is the stabilizer at $v \in S^n$.

(This new block matrix is clearly orthogonal since the dot product of two different columns are still zero and dot product of a column with itself is $1$)

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Let $B \in O(n+1)$ and $Bv = v$ so that $B$ is in the stabilizer at $v$. Then the rightmost column of $B$ has to be

$$\begin{matrix}
\vdots \\
0\\
1
\end{matrix}$$

(we just make a direct computation of $Bv$)

and for $B$ to be orthogonal two different columns dot producted with eachother has to be zero. In particular for the rightmost culumn $ (b_{i,1},...,b_{i,n+1}) \ \cdot \ (0,...,0,1) = 0$ if $i \neq n+1$ which implies that $b_{i,n+1} = 0$ for all $i \neq n+1$. What this says is that $B$ is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
B' & \vdots \\
  & 0\\
\dots 0  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

for some $n \times n$ matrix $B'$. Verifying that $B'$ is orthogonal is easy using the dot product of columns definition (dot product of two different columns has to be $0$ and the dot product of a column with itself is $1$).

It is simple to check that any matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
B' & \vdots \\
  & 0\\
\dots 0  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $B' \in O(n)$ fixes $v$.

This proves that $O(n+1)_v = O(n)$.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Now on to proving the result about homotopy groups.

The long exact sequence in homotopy groups associated to the fiber sequence

$$O(n)=O(n+1)_v \rightarrow O(n+1) \rightarrow O(n+1)v = S^n$$

(we used transitivity for last equality)

then becomes

$$...\rightarrow \pi_{i+1}(S^n) \rightarrow \pi_{i}(O(n)) \rightarrow \pi_i(O(n+1)) \rightarrow \pi_{i}(S^n) \rightarrow ...$$

Then if $i+1 < n,$ $\pi_{i+1}(S^n) = \pi_{i}(S^n) = 0$ so the map $$\pi_{i}(O(n)) \rightarrow \pi_i(O(n+1))$$ is an isomorphism if $i \leq n-2$. Then for induction it is simple to prove that $$\pi_{i}(O(n+k)) \rightarrow \pi_i(O(n+k+1))$$ is an isomorphism for positive $k$ if $i \leq n-2$ since $i \leq n-2$ implies that $i \leq n+k-2$.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Could you please look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618291/problem-22-35-in-modern-classical-homotopy-theory-by-jeffery-strom-on-pg-510 if you have time?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if I count as a reputable source, but here is an outline of the proof that the action is transitive.  Then Noel's answer finishes off the rest of the problem.

**Lemma 1**  The set $O(n)$ is a group under matrix multiplication.  Further, $A\in O(n)$ iff the columns of $A$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof hint:**  Recall that $( A^{-1})^t = (A^t)^{-1}$ for any invertible matrix $A$.  Also, note that the entries of $A^t A$ are dot products of columns of $A$, and $A^t A = A^{-1} A = I$.  $\square$

Let $\vec{p}\in S^n$ denote the north pole:  $\vec{p} = (1,0,...,0)^t$.

**Lemma 2**   Suppose for every $\vec{x}\in S^n$, there is a matrix $A \in O(n)$ with $A\vec{p} = \vec{x}$.  Then the action is transitive.

**Proof hint:**  If $A\in O(n)$ moves $\vec{p}$ to $\vec{x}$, then $A^{-1}\in O(n)$ and $A^{-1}$ moves $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{p}$.  $\square$

**Lemma 3:**  For any $n\times n$ matrix $A$, $A\vec{p}$ is the first column of $A$.

**Lemma 4:**  Given any $\vec{x}\in S^n$, the set $\{\vec{x}\}$ can be extended to a orthonormal basis $\{ \vec{x}, \vec{v}_1,... \vec{v}_{n-1}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof hint:**  Induction on dimension $n$.

**Lemma 5**  Given any $\vec{x}\in S^n$, there is a matrix $A$ for which $A\vec{p} =\vec{x}$.

**Proof hint:**  Use Lemma 4 and 1.

Comment: Could you please look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618291/problem-22-35-in-modern-classical-homotopy-theory-by-jeffery-strom-on-pg-510 if you have time?