# Problem 22.39(a) in " Modern classical homotopy Theory " by Jeffery Strom on pg.511.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, k-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Here is the problem:

Suppose $R$ is a field.
(a) Show that $h^{n}(?) = Hom_{R}(H_{n}(?; R), R)$ is a cohomology theory defined on (at least) the category of finite CW complexes.

I got a hint to prove the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms but I am unable to do this, could anyone help me in proving so, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify that $\text{Hom}_{R-\text{Mod}}(H_n(-;R),R)$ is a cohomology theory we use the fact that $\text{Hom}_{R-\text{Mod}}(-,R):R-\text{Mod} \rightarrow R-\text{Mod}$ preserves short exact sequences of finitely generated $R-$modules if $R$ is a field and actually long exact sequences of finitely generated $R-$modules.

Verifying that if $f \simeq g$ then $h^i(f) = h^i(g)$ is easy since we know that $H_i(f) = H_i(g)$ which means that the homotopy invariance axiom is satisfied.

Verifying exactness of a long exact sequence $...\rightarrow h^i(X) \rightarrow h^i(A) \rightarrow h^i(X,A) \rightarrow ...$ is simple because we know that $... \rightarrow H_i(X,A;R) \rightarrow H_i(A;R) \rightarrow H_i(X;R) \rightarrow ...$ is exact and that all $H_i(X,A;R)$ are finitely generated $R-$modules if $(X,A)$ is a $CW-$pair with $X$ finite.

This means that after applying the functor $\text{Hom}_{R-\text{Mod}}(-,R)$, the sequence is still exact which means that the exactness axiom is satisfied.

You can try to prove that the functor $\text{Hom}_{R-\text{Mod}}(-,R)$ takes coproducts to products which means that the additivity condition is satisfied since $\bigsqcup H_i(X_{\alpha};R) \rightarrow H_i(X;R)$ is an isomorphism if $\bigsqcup X_{\alpha} = X$.

If you have any questions just comment so I can explain my thoughts more clearly! Hope that helped.

Comment: Why we use this fact you mentioned in the second line? does it make calculation easier?

Comment: That the functor preserves exact sequences of finitely generated $R-$modules? Because $H_i(X,A;R)$ is finitely generated if $X$ is a finite $CW-$complex. I don't know if it preserves sequences of non-finitely generated modules.

Comment: Could you please include details of the proof of each axiom?

Comment: where is the dimension axiom? and additivity axiom?

Comment: Do not we require homotopy colimit to prove that the cofibre sequence induces a long exact sequence?

Comment: Dimension axiom is trivial, and the long exact sequence has nothing to do with homotopy colimits and cofibre sequences. If $A \subset X$ then $... \rightarrow H_i(X,A;R) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(A) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(X) \rightarrow ...$ is exact and all the modules are finitely generated if $X$ is a finite $CW-$complex which means that exactness is preserved when applying $\text{Hom}(-,R)$

Comment: Why dimension axiom is trivial?

Comment: What is $h^i(*)$ where $*$ is a one point space? Try and compute it from the definition.

Comment: I do not know how to compute it.

Comment: @Mathstupid Do you know what a module is? Do you know what $\text{Hom}_{R-\text{mod}}(M,N)$ is for two $R-$modules $M$ and $N$?

Comment: No I do not know.

Comment: So why are you attempting to solve a problem that you don't even understand, make sure you understand the problem before trying to solve it. @Mathstupid

Comment: I am sorry I know what is a module I googled it … I think the Hom is zero

Comment: I am so sorry …. but I have a professor who assigns problems to us without giving us the tools for solving them …. I am really so sorry. could you please continue answering my questions …. I am really fed up with my professor attitude but I can not do anything.

Comment: @mathstupid there's nothing to be sorry about friend, but I think it's better for you to just tell your professor that you don't understand the problems he is giving you, is this something that other students say aswell? That they dont understand? What course is this for?

Comment: Is this a first course in algebraic topology? Stroms homotopy theory is really, really bad for a first introduction to algebraic topology.

Comment: Now I want to ask you about some hints that was given to us: first to look at Theorem 22.37 and in our problem here we want to show the first natural transformation of the theorem. could you please explain this hint more for me?

Comment: Unfortunately Yes it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106762/discussion-between-noel-lundstrom-and-mathstupid).