# Problem 22.39(b) in " Modern classical homotopy Theory " by Jeffery Strom on pg.511.(u is the natural transformation of cohomology theories.)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory, group-cohomology, k-theory

Here is the problem:

Suppose $R$ is a field.

(a) Show that $h^{n}(?) = Hom_{R}(H_{n}(?; R), R)$ is a cohomology theory defined on (at least) the category of finite CW complexes.

(b) Show that $u$ is the natural transformation of cohomology theories.

Where $u$ is defined in the following paragraph:

> [image]

And we also should have solved the following problem before trying to solve 22.39(b):

Show that  is natural in both variables. That is suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y, u \in \tilde{H^{*}}(Y), \alpha \in \tilde{H_{*}}(X).$ Then we can form $$<u, f_{*}(\alpha)> \in \tilde{H}_{n-k}(Y)$$ And $$<f^{*}(u), \alpha)> \in \tilde{H}_{n-k}(X).$$

Where $<?,?>$ is the Pairing Cohomology with homology.

Could anyone tell me how may 22.35 help me in the solution of (b)?

Also, could anyone help me in the solution in general?

Comment: Do you mean that $\langle ?, ? \rangle$ is the *cap* product?

Comment: No it is not sorry @NoelLundström