# Problem 22.35 in "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory " by Jeffery Strom on pg.510.(2)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Here is the question:

Show that $\langle ?,?\rangle$ (defined below) is natural in both variables. That is suppose $f\colon X \rightarrow Y,\ u \in \tilde{H^{*}}(Y),\ \alpha \in \tilde{H_{*}}(X).$ Then we can form $$ \langle u, f_{*}(\alpha)\rangle \in \tilde{H}_{n-k}(Y)$$ and $$\langle f^{*}(u), \alpha\rangle \in \tilde{H}_{n-k}(X).$$

Show that $$f_{*}(\langle f^{*}(u), \alpha \rangle) = \langle u, f_{*}(\alpha) \rangle. $$

The question depends on the following paragraph of pairing Cohomology with Homology in "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory " by Jeffery Strom:

> [image]

So, we are not speaking about cap product it is just pairing. Could anyone help me in solving this, please?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I am stuck in the solution is it through diagrams or what and from where to start? @William ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're supposed to solve it with the definition that Strom writes down. Try writing down the maps representing $\langle u, f_*(\alpha) \rangle$ and $f_*(\langle f^*(u), \alpha \rangle)$ and compare them.

Comment: Is $f_{*} (\alpha) = \alpha \circ f^{*}$ or just $\alpha \circ f.$@William

Comment: How should I start using the given diagram ? @William at which step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha \in \tilde{H}_{n}(X;B)$ then we can represent it with a homotopy class of maps $\alpha\colon S^{n+t} \to X\wedge K(B,t)$ for $t$ sufficiently large relative to $n$ (see Strom page 506 for his definition of ordinary homology). Given $f\colon X \to Y$, in order to get a class in $\tilde{H}_n(Y;B)$ we can form the composition $(f\wedge id_{K(B,t)})\circ \alpha\colon S^{n+t} \to Y \wedge K(B,t)$; this is $f_*(\alpha)$ (I can't find where Strom explicitly states this but this is typically how it's defined). Analogously, as $u\in \tilde{H^k}(Y;A)$ is represented by a map $Y \to K(A, k)$ the pullback $f^*(u)$ to $X$ is represented by the composition $u\circ f\colon X \to K(A,k)$.

Then a representative map for $\langle u, f_*(\alpha) \rangle \in \tilde{H}_{n-k}(Y; A\otimes B)$ can then be given by

$$\begin{align} S^{n + t} &\stackrel{\alpha}{\to} X \wedge K(B,t)\\
&\stackrel{f\wedge id}{\to}Y\wedge K(B,t)\\
&\stackrel{\bar\Delta\wedge id}{\to} Y \wedge Y \wedge K(B,t)\\
&\stackrel{id \wedge u\wedge id}{\to} Y\wedge K(A,k)\wedge K(B,t)\\
&\stackrel{id \wedge c}{\to} Y \wedge K(A\otimes B, k + t) \end{align} $$

according to Strom's definition.

You now have the ingredients you need to come up with a representative for the class $f_*(\langle f^*(u), \alpha \rangle)$. You should do that, and then verify that it agrees with the map that I wrote down (at least up to homotopy).

Comment: Why you are saying in the first line map**s**? and why $\alpha$ should be represented by a homotopy class?

Comment: Is the answer of the first question that we have $n$ and $t$?

Comment: what about my question before last in the comments above?

Comment: which part of page 506 do you want me to look at? do you want me to look at 22.24?

Comment: Strom _defines_ ordinary homology (p.506) as a colimit of homotopy groups (which is eventually constant by Problem 22.24). This is why I'm representing a homology class with a map $S^{n+t} \to X \wedge K(B,t)$ (just like Strom does when he defines the $\langle, \rangle$ pairing) and I say map**s** because any homotopic map would also be a representative.

Comment: why smash in the composition at the beginning of line 4?

Comment: $f_{*}$ is defined on page 11 in Strom.

Comment: Why we smashed $u$ with the identity? and why we require the map $c$ at the end and why this $c$ is not smashed with the identity?

Comment: Why did not we use the diagonal map?

Comment: I fixed the errors in my sequence of compositions, it looks like Strom's definition now

Comment: I think $u \in \tilde{H}^*$ not $\tilde{H}^k$ by the given …  am I correct?

Comment: Oh haha I see, in his problem statement Strom does write "$*$" for his degrees in cohomology and homology. But, since both of the output classes are in degree $n-k$ and he only defines the pairing for homogenous elements I suspect this was a typo (or that the degrees are implied). If you want to consider non-homogeneous $u \in \tilde{H^*}$ and $\alpha \in \tilde{H_*}$, you can use bilinearity of $\langle, \rangle$ to write $\langle u, \alpha \rangle = \sum_{k,n} \langle u_k, \alpha_n \rangle$ where $u_k$ and $\alpha_n$ are homogenous of degree $k$ and $n$ respectively.

Comment: where did you get that $u$ from Y to $K(A, k)$ ? should not it to $K(B,t)$?

Comment: no because $u$ is a cohomology class in $\tilde{H^k}(Y;A)$ so it's represented by a map $Y \to K(A,k)$. (compare to Strom's definition of the pairing)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619898/problem-22-39b-in-modern-classical-homotopy-theory-by-jeffery-strom-on-pg?noredirect=1#comment7444952_3619898

Comment: I am struggling is the starting line just $f$?

Comment: or $u \circ f$ ?

Comment: I think I will start by $\alpha$ also .... correct?

Comment: yes start with $\alpha$, and you will do something with $f$ at the end

Comment: I think I am good now BIG THANKS :)

Comment: Could you please look at the question of the empty mind mentioned bove (if you have time)?

Comment: I calculated $\langle f^*(u), \alpha \rangle$ . Now to calculate the required, should I compose with $f \wedge id$?

Comment: I did what I mention above and they were exactly the same.

Comment: So I do not require diagram chasing... am I correct?

Comment: Yes you're correct, when you write out the compositions representing these two homology classes you should find that they are the same.